# Modify prefetched objects

Tags: django

Is it possible to modify prefetched objects without using save()?

```
class First(models.Model):
field = models.IntegerField()

class Second(models.Model):
first = models.ForeignKey(First, related_name='seconds')
some = models.IntegerField()

qs = First.objects.filter(field=12).prefetch_related('seconds')
qs[0].seconds.all()[0].some = 999
qs[0].seconds.all()[0] == 999 # should be True
```

UPDATE:

I found what was wrong. First need evaluate queryset e.g. len(qs) after filter.
I want to alter my question slightly. Can i modify foreign key relationship without hitting db?

```
qs = First.objects.filter(field=12).prefetch_related('seconds')
len(qs)
print(len(qs[0].seconds.all())) # output: 5
qs[0].seconds.all()[0].first_id = 2    
print(len(qs[0].seconds.all())) # output: 4
```

Comment: I think that you have oversimplified your example. I tried to run your code. I changed the line to `f = First.objects.filter(field=12).prefetch_related('seconds').get()` so that it returned a single instance instead of a queryset. After making that change, `f.seconds.all()[0] == 999` is `True`.

Comment: Your example code would error - `f` is a QuerySet and does not have an attribute "seconds"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing

```
f.seconds.all()[0].some = 999
f.seconds.all()[0] == 999 # should be True
```

Do this..

```
first_object = f.seconds.all()[0]
first_object.some = 999
first_object.some == 999 #true
```